# Leaking kitchen faucet

Tags: faucet

My kitchen faucet has a slow leak coming from the faucet.

I removed the hot side knob (while forgetting to turn off the shutoff valve first) and some parts went airborne while I rushed to turn off the water.

Which part or parts do I need to replace?

I think the spring and the rubber object next to it go in the hole in the well.

What order do they go in if I am right?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring goes into the bottom of the cartridge followed by the rubber bushing/washer. The leak is probably coming from some of the other "o" rings or seals in the cartridge. You might want to consider just buying a new cartridge.